# Como pegar o valor inteiro do "days" de um DateInterval

Tags: php, dateinterval

Como faço para pegar o valor `days` de um `DateInterval` através do método `date_interval_format()`?
Tentei da seguinte maneira, mas não deu certo:

`$var = date_interval_format($diferenca, '%days');`

[image]

Comment: Já tentou utilizar algo como  $diferenca->format('%d days'); ?

Comment: Já sim. Dessa maneira é retornado "6 days", e não os 36 que eu preciso ! (6 dias + 30 dias de 1 mês)

Comment: O que tens em `$diferenca`? segundos? não daria para dividir por 60*60*24 e ter dias? com um arredondamento opcional.

Comment: O $diferença é uma variavel do tipo DateInterval, como mostro na imagem a cima ! E quero pegar o valor 36 do days

Comment: Podes mostrar onde obténs esse `$diferenca`?

Comment: Desse modo Sergio :
$diferenca = $dataFinal->diff($dataInicial);
Faço a diferença entre dois DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz dessa forma e deu certo:

```
$var = $diferenca->days;
```

`$var` recebeu o valor 36 que eu queria !

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o manual do PHP podes usar `format('%a')` para formatar uma diferença de datas, ou `days`.

Ambos dão o que procuras.

### `format('%a')`

[No manual diz](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

> Total number of days as a result of a DateTime::diff()

ou seja o *numero total de dias entre as duas datas*.

Exemplo:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-23');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%a'); // dá 12
```

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/fork/XfSnAI

### `days`

Diz também no [manual da Classe Datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) que têm uma propriedade `days` cuja descrição é:

> **days**
>   If the DateInterval object was created by DateTime::diff(), then this is the total number of days between the start and end dates. Otherwise, days will be FALSE.

Traduzido seria:

Se o objeto intervalo fôr criado com DateTime::diff() então será o numero total de dias entre as datas. Caso contrário o valor será `false`.

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/E8M2n1